# jQuery add delay if element does not exist yet

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following jQuery code, but that does not work well, because the page is also rendered with a lot of javascript, so document ready is not working in this case.
When we add a `setTimeout` to the code, then it works well.

But we want to change this into the following. We first would like to check if the select field already exists and already got the required value. If not then it should add a delay and check again after 500 ms.

How can we achieve that?

CODE;

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select[name="country_id"]').val('BE').change();
      })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could check if the element itself is loaded: https://www.nikitakazakov.com/js-wait-until-loaded-dom-element

Comment: Alternatively set the value on the server where the select is created